# Sql Server issue

Tags: sql-server-2008

I hope this is not off-topic, but I have a real problem that I oculd use some advice on.

I have an application that upgrades its own Sql Server database (from previous versions) on startup. Normally this works well, but a new version has to alter several nvarchar column widths.

On live databases with large amount of data in the table this is taking a very long time. There appear to be two problems - one is that Sql Server seems to be processing the data (possibly rewriting it), even though that isn't actually being changed, and the other is that the transaction log gobbles up a huge amount of space.

Is there any way to circumvent this issue? It's only a plain Alter Table... Alter Column command, changing nvarchar(x) to nvarchar(x+n), nothing fancy, but it is causing an 'issue' and much dissatisfaction in the field. If there was a way of changing the column width without processing the existing data, and  somehow suppressing the transaction log stuff, that would be handy.

It doesn't seem to be a problem with Oracle databases.

An example command:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE table_name='ResourceBookings' AND column_name = ('ResourceBookerKey1') AND character_maximum_length <= 50)
    ALTER TABLE [ResourceBookings] ALTER COLUMN [ResourceBookerKey1] NVARCHAR(80) NULL
```

As you can see, the table is only changed if the column width needs to be increased

TIA

Comment: I realise you describe the code but it may still be helpful to post the actual code.

Comment: Sounds like you have some page splits going on but I would not think that would be necessary with VAR.

Comment: Are there any indexes with this field?

Comment: Any indexes which depend on the column are dropped beforehand and recreated afterwards, but even if there are no indexes it takes a very long time.

Comment: If it's definitely expanding the width of the column, then it's very odd - that ought to be a metadata only change, so far as I'm aware (since variable length columns don't reserve space at the row level - they only occupy the space they need + a couple of bytes to indicate the size of that space). Was it definitely `nvarchar` before?

Comment: Could I be barking up the wrong tree? Could it be the re-creation of the indexes afterwards that is taking all the time? I suppose that's easy to test, but if so it leaves me with much the same problem - how to avoid the huge transaction log and time taken.

Answer (score 1):

Before upgrading, make sure the SQL Server database's Recovery Model is set to "Simple".  Go to SSMS, right-click the database, select properties, and then click on the Options pages.  Record the "Recovery Mode" value.  Set the Recovery Model to "Simple", if it's not already (I assume it's set to FULL).

Then run the upgrade.  After the upgrade, you can restore the value back to what it was.

Alternately you can script it with something like this:

Before upgrade:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
```

After upgrade:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET RECOVERY FULL;
```